# Webpack Module parse failed (.po)

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-loader

I have problem with webpack **.po** loader.

What I am doing is

**package.json **

```
- "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
- "po-loader": "^0.4.2",
- "po2json": "^1.0.0-alpha",
```

In **webpack entry** file I am collecting my **.po** files (with all others .js, .css etc.)

After running **yarn build** webpack compile all files (my .po files are inside)
[image]

And then I am getting this error with parsing (see below in webpack config file that I have *po loader* in loaders)

Why?

[image]

In **webpack config** file I have loader (*po2json* )

Webpack.config is here

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  // all different pages are defined here
  entry,
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './webroot/dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkname: '[name].js',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:80/dist/',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.jsx', '.js', '.po'],
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js(x?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css?url=false',
      },
      {
        test: /\.po$/,
        loader: 'json!po'
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
    ],
  },
...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with webpack 4.35.3 and po-loader 0.5.0.

I'm not using `json-loader` because it's not necessary with newer webpack versions. Webpack can load JSON files "natively" now.

For me the problem was that `po-loader` returns a stringified JSON object but webpack doesn't actually know that the returned output is JSON instead of JavaScript.

Setting `type` to `json` when configuring the loader fixes this.

For example:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.po$/,
        type: "json", // This line fixes the problem
        use: [{
            loader: 'po-loader'
        }]
      }
    ]
```